# Getting errors, but I am not sure what they mean

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a program, but I keep getting a couple of errors, that I have never seen before. This is my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.*;

public class Project1
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("artists.txt") ); //read from file
    Scanner console new Scanner(System.in); //read from user input 


int sum = 0; //sum of revenue
String artist; //user input
int revenue = 0; //store yearly revenue


System.out.println("Please enter the name of a band/artist: ");
artist = console.next();   

String[] tokens = artist.split(" "); 

while(inFile.hasNext() )
{
  if (tokens == inFile.hasNext() )
  {  
    if (inFile.Next == (2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012) );
    {
      if (inFile.hasNext() )
      {
        revenue = inFile.nextInt();
        sum += revenue;
        System.out.print("sum");
      }
    }
  }
}

inFile.close();
```

The errors I get are as follow:

```
Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement [Line 13]
Error: Syntax error on token "==", Name expected after this token [Line 30]
```

If anyone happens to see any other mistakes, feel free to point them out. Thank you.

Comment: If you're learning Java, I think you should start with simpler Java examples. Your code has basic syntactic errors...

Answer (score 4):

You're missing an assignment here:

```
Scanner console new Scanner(System.in);
```

and this:

```
if (inFile.Next == (2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012) );
```

(leaving aside the trailing semi-colon)

isn't anything I would recognise in Java. I would break this down into smaller units and try and get small components working one at a atime, otherwise it's easy to confuse yourself with a large number of compiler errors.

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, I have another question regarding the second line: I have a file formatted like this: "name year revenue", all in one line. The name gets repeated several times. How can I make it so rather than my program going to the next line, it'll skip the year and add up the revenue in that line, to the revenue in other lines?

Comment: I don't think I can really answer that briefly in a comment! Sorry. Perhaps another question...

Comment: Thank you, I will ask another one.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an assignment operator `=`:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You won't be able to do this:

```
if (inFile.Next == (2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012) );
```

I'm guessing you want:

```
if (revenue == 2005 || revenue == 2006 || ...)) {
   sum += revenue;
}
```

or simply

```
  if (revenue >= 2005 && revenue <= 2012) {
```

Comment: Thank you. That is not quite what I am trying to do. I have a file, formatted as such: "artist year revenue". This is repeated over several lines, with different artists and years. Some artists appear more than once. I want my program to find the artist the user inputs, then add up the revenue for all the different years. My attempt with the second line was to have my program find the year, skip it, and then add up the revenue.

Comment: @user2236308 the syntax you have used is not supported in Java, so you're going to have to do it that way.

Comment: @Logan Dam Dully noted. I am curious as to how I can make my program read on the same line, rather than move on to the next. I was trying to create a condition which forces it to do so. Thank you.

Comment: @user2236308 if you can change the format of the file you can include delimiters and search for those delimiters when you read the line and extract the data you need.